# Android ListPopupWindow Hiding Keyboard

Tags: android

When I set InputMethodMode to ListPopupWindowInputMethodMode.Needed , Popup window stays behind keyboard. When I start scrolling list of popup window, It shows above the keyboard. I want to keep popup window behind keyboard all time. It seems during scrolling of list , InputMethodMode is overridden.

```
        m_listPopup = new ListPopupWindow(Context);
        m_listPopup.AnchorView = this;
        m_listPopup.SetAdapter(m_adapter);
        m_listPopup.Height = (int)Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.suggestions_popover_height);
        m_listPopup.Width = (int)Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.suggestions_popover_width);
        m_listPopup.InputMethodMode = ListPopupWindowInputMethodMode.Needed;
```

[image]